# Ways to test bar charts with few bars to see if they come from the same distribution?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, survey, ordinal-data, histogram

I have survey data with ordinal/categorical data. Most of the time the answers to question are Yes/No. I want to compare the bar charts (normalized) of yes/no from participants who gave a particular answer to a previous question.

- Eg. Looking at users who answered yes to Q.4, then those that answered no to Q.4, did they answer similarly to Q.6? This will give two distributions/ratios for instance (0.4,0.6) and (0.35,0.65).

Should I use a Chi-squared test? Or use a measure of distribution distance similarity like the [Jensen–Shannon divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Chi-squared test of independence in this case.

I think it will be much easier to apply than the (slightly overkill) Jensen-Shannon divergence.

Comment: what does **test of independence** mean when using this test?

Comment: This refers to the test, developed by Karl Pearson, which is used to asses the **independence** of two categorical variables. It employs a **Chi-squared test statistic**, but many other tests do, so it is important to specify that we are using the Chi-squared test of independence. For more information, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test or http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/independence.aspx .

Comment: great thanks, so the independence refers to them not being essentially the same distribution?

Comment: The independence refers to whether or not the two categorical variables depend on each other. If some variable X and Y are independent, the distribution of X is the same for all levels of Y (in your case 2, yes/no), and vice versa.